# Parse or Convert TimeSpan to string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, timespan

I need to parse a TimeSpan to a string using a user provided format

I've tried a number of options including various RegEx.Replace and Parse options.

In the below I've added an Extension method to TimeSpan.

```
public void should_return_hours_and_minutes_and_seconds()
{
    _ts = new TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10);

    var format = "HH:mm:ss"; // Input by User. Goal is to include other formats

    var returnedVal = _ts.ToString(format);

    Assert.That(returnedVal, Is.EqualTo("49:30:10")); // Days rollup to hours
}
```

Comment: What formats are you looking for?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code

```
public void should_return_hours_and_minutes_and_seconds()
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime(time_span.Ticks);
    string time = d.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Same question is found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384912/how-to-achieve-timespan-to-string-conversion

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shyam but the above does not include the hours from the TimeSpan days portion - TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10). Result is "01:30:10" - Glenn